# Efficient way to generate large randomized data in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to generate a large random data set spark. I essentially want to start at `2018-12-01 09:00:00` and for each new row, the timestamp will change by `scala.util.Random.nextInt(3)` seconds. (The `timestamp` column is the only meaningful column)

I want this to still work even when I try to generate trillions of rows on a large cluster, so I'm trying to generate it in batches of 100 elements at a time since trillions of rows cannot fit into a `Seq`.

There are a few problems with this code such as the `var` and I'm not sure about my use of `union`. I'm wondering if anyone has a better idea of how to do this.

```
import Math.{max, min}
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SaveMode}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object DataGenerator extends SparkEnv {

  import spark.implicits._

  val batchSize = 100
  val rnd = scala.util.Random

  // randomly generates a DataFrame with n Rows
  def generateTimestampData(n: Int): DataFrame = {
    val timestampDataFields = Seq(StructField("timestamp", TimestampType, false))
    val initDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], StructType(timestampDataFields))
    def loop(data: DataFrame, lastTime: Long, _n: Int): DataFrame = {
      if (_n == 0) {
        val w = Window.orderBy("timestamp")
        data.withColumn("eventID", concat(typedLit("event"), row_number().over(w)))
      } else {
        var thisTime = lastTime
        def rts(ts: Long): Stream[Long] = ts #:: { thisTime = ts + rnd.nextInt(3) * 1000; rts(thisTime) }
        val thisBatch = rts(lastTime)
          .map(new Timestamp(_))
          .take(min(batchSize, _n))
          .toDF("timestamp")
        loop(data union thisBatch, thisTime, max(_n - batchSize, 0))
      }
    }
    loop(initDF, valueOf("2018-12-01 09:00:00").getTime(), n)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val w = Window.orderBy("timestamp")
    val df = generateTimestampData(10015)
      .withColumn("part", floor(row_number().over(w) / 100))
    df.repartition(27)
      .write
      .partitionBy("part")
      .option("compression", "snappy")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .parquet("data/generated/ts_data")
  }

}
```

The above code results in a DataFrame with 10,015 rows that looks something like this.

```
+-------------------+----------+----+
|          timestamp|   eventID|part|
+-------------------+----------+----+
|2018-12-01 11:43:09|event10009| 100|
|2018-12-01 11:43:02|event10003| 100|
|2018-12-01 11:43:11|event10012| 100|
|2018-12-01 11:43:10|event10011| 100|
|2018-12-01 11:43:08|event10007| 100|
|2018-12-01 11:43:02|event10001| 100|
|2018-12-01 11:43:08|event10008| 100|
|2018-12-01 11:43:12|event10013| 100|
|2018-12-01 11:43:09|event10010| 100|
|2018-12-01 11:43:14|event10014| 100|
|2018-12-01 10:11:54| event4357|  43|
|2018-12-01 10:47:33| event6524|  65|
|2018-12-01 10:23:08| event5064|  50|
|2018-12-01 10:23:02| event5060|  50|
|2018-12-01 10:23:39| event5099|  50|
|2018-12-01 10:22:25| event5019|  50|
|2018-12-01 09:16:36| event1042|  10|
|2018-12-01 09:16:03| event1008|  10|
|2018-12-01 09:16:13| event1017|  10|
|2018-12-01 09:17:28| event1092|  10|
+-------------------+----------+----+
```

Answer (score 7):

You can implement an RDD that performs the random data generation in parallel, as in the following example.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import org.apache.spark.{Partition, TaskContext}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

// Each random partition will hold `numValues` items
final class RandomPartition[A: ClassTag](val index: Int, numValues: Int, random: => A) extends Partition {
  def values: Iterator[A] = Iterator.fill(numValues)(random)
}

// The RDD will parallelize the workload across `numSlices`
final class RandomRDD[A: ClassTag](@transient private val sc: SparkContext, numSlices: Int, numValues: Int, random: => A) extends RDD[A](sc, deps = Seq.empty) {

  // Based on the item and executor count, determine how many values are
  // computed in each executor. Distribute the rest evenly (if any).
  private val valuesPerSlice = numValues / numSlices
  private val slicesWithExtraItem = numValues % numSlices

  // Just ask the partition for the data
  override def compute(split: Partition, context: TaskContext): Iterator[A] =
    split.asInstanceOf[RandomPartition[A]].values

  // Generate the partitions so that the load is as evenly spread as possible
  // e.g. 10 partition and 22 items -> 2 slices with 3 items and 8 slices with 2
  override protected def getPartitions: Array[Partition] =
    ((0 until slicesWithExtraItem).view.map(new RandomPartition[A](_, valuesPerSlice + 1, random)) ++
      (slicesWithExtraItem until numSlices).view.map(new RandomPartition[A](_, valuesPerSlice, random))).toArray

}
```

Once you have this you can use it passing your own random data generator to get an `RDD[Int]`

```
val rdd = new RandomRDD(spark.sparkContext, 10, 22, scala.util.Random.nextInt(100) + 1)
rdd.foreach(println)
/*
 * outputs:
 * 30
 * 86
 * 75
 * 20
 * ...
 */
```

or an `RDD[(Int, Int, Int)]`

```
def rand = scala.util.Random.nextInt(100) + 1
val rdd = new RandomRDD(spark.sparkContext, 10, 22, (rand, rand, rand))
rdd.foreach(println)
/*
 * outputs:
 * (33,22,15)
 * (65,24,64)
 * (41,81,44)
 * (58,7,18)
 * ...
 */
```

and of course you can wrap it in a `DataFrame` very easily as well:

```
spark.createDataFrame(rdd).show()
/*
 * outputs:
 * +---+---+---+
 * | _1| _2| _3|
 * +---+---+---+
 * |100| 48| 92|
 * | 34| 40| 30|
 * | 98| 63| 61|
 * | 95| 17| 63|
 * | 68| 31| 34|
 * .............
 */
```

Notice how in this case the generated data is different every time the `RDD`/`DataFrame` is acted upon. By changing the implementation of `RandomPartition` to actually store the values instead of generating them on the fly, you can have a stable set of random items, while still retaining the flexibility and scalability of this approach.

One nice property of the stateless approach is that you can generate huge dataset even locally. The following ran in a few seconds on my laptop:

```
new RandomRDD(spark.sparkContext, 10, Int.MaxValue, 42).count
// returns: 2147483647
```

Comment: In my version of spark, there is no `spark.createDataFrame(rdd: RDD[_])` instead, there's a `spark.createDataFrame(rdd: RDD[_], beanClass: Class[_])`.

Comment: You have to specify the output class explicitly. What version is it?

Comment: It is version 2.4.0

Comment: Pass the expected output explicitly, either with the `Class` or with the `StructType`. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@createDataFrame(rowRDD:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: If you get `java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field ` error, you may want to change the call by name in `(val index: Int, numValues: Int, random: => A)` to call by value `(val index: Int, numValues: Int, random:  A)`

Comment: @stefanobaghino With the similar approach how can I add custom schema to this randomly generated dataset. I have a case class for the schema and my spark version is 3.3.2 and createDataFrame method takes parameter as rdd: Row[_], structType: StructType.